# How to prevent files in websever can be download

Tags: html, apache, webserver

some files, such as "abc.pdf" were uploaded in to an apache webserver "www.xxx.com" which saved in a directory called "yyy". I dont know why google listed out of my file as "www.xxx.com/yyy/abc.pdf" when I search with the file name abc. Now, any people can downolad it....

How can I prevent this, and how can I delete the list on google ?!

Thanks,

Comment: This question is probably better suited to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. You may need to look into modifying your robot.txt file to disallow access to the file/folder.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent this

Delete the file. Move it out of the webroot. Configure the server so it gives a Not Authorized error when people hit the URL. etc. Basically: Stop publishing it.

> how can I delete the list on google

It should go away after a while if you do any of the above. You could also tell the bot not to go near it with `robots.txt`. [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters) has a URL removal feature.

Comment: Thanks Quentin! By the way, my site is hosted since year 2008, it is never been listed on google's search engin until this year. Is that google changed something on their search engine? When did the robots.txt function ?

Comment: Google change their search engine all the time. Robots.txt has been in use since 1994.